# Cypress runs old code instead of running updated code changes

Tags: node.js, cypress, yarnpkg

I'm running into an issue with Cypress.io that I don't see too much helpful information about out there. Essentially, whenever I make changes to my code (e.g. implement a new method, remove an old method, etc.) and save, the test runner goes ahead and executes my test file as it should. However, it runs the code that was present prior to the changes. I've tried implementing hooks, eliminating hooks, closing the dashboard after each run, clearing the app data; not sure what the source of the issue is though.

For context, I'm running cypress using Yarn (`yarn cypress open` to open the dashboard) and am keeping my test files saved in `cypress/integration/`.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: similar problem on node 14.x, cypress 6.2.1. Doing this:
 
Cypress.automation(
    'remote:debugger:protocol',
    {
      command: 'Network.setCacheDisabled',
      params: { cacheDisabled: true }
    })

didn't help.

Comment: @estastepe What is the directory structure of you project? There may be things that are loaded at different times. Is there some code that you could share to help reproduce the issue? I don't believe I am having this issue but happy to try to replicate with some code changes. Does killing and rekicking cypress pick up the new code just fine?

Comment: Please focus on the terminal where Cypress runner is running. It provides all the information regarding which shows up in Cypress runner .

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem comes from the browser cache, as you can see in [this conversation](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19423#issuecomment-1546918126).

If not, maybe some preprocessor is hiding something. Double-check these types of problems on your files:

- syntax errors
- paths of imports

I've suffered the same problem multiple times. Clearing the cache doesn't work. To find the hidden error, be patient and systematic:

- Look for help on the "Problems" panel from your editor (vscode in my case).
- Put some `console.log()` and comment your last changes incrementally until you can see that the file is renewed by cypress.

I wonder if some log message on the cypress CI warns about it.

### An example I suffered

My test file `test.js` has:

```js
import MainViewPOM from '../pom/MainViewPOM';
```

and `MainViewPOM.js` has:

```js
import DialogPOM from '../DialogPOM';
```

This last path should have one dot, not two. The import fails internally, and nothing warns me. Cypress ignores the new version of the file.

### More generally

- When you have a JS error, cypress throws an `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat`.
- When you have a file linking error like mine, cypress keeps the old version of the test that imports the file where the import is failing.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and what helped me then is clearing the cache before each test as it seems that Cypress is not disabling cache by default.

**I've added a custom command:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('clearCache', { prevSubject: false }, () => {
  localStorage.clear()
  indexedDB.deleteDatabase('cypress')
  return true
})
```

**And then I called it in `beforeEach()` hook to have my cache cleared before each running test:**

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  cy.clearCache();
});
```

I hope it works for you. If you have any questions please let me know